# Collect multiple data from PHP page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following ajax script to login a user to my site. The ajax script upon submit passes the form data to my page validate_login.php:

index.php:

```
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/flip/jquery.flip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/flip/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
var myusername = $("#myusername").val();
var mypassword = $("#mypassword").val();
if (myusername == null || myusername == "" || mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
if (myusername == null || myusername == "") { document.forms["form"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
if (mypassword == null || mypassword == "") { document.forms["form"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
$( ".home_column" ).effect( "shake" ); 
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("include/validate_login.php", {
username1: myusername,
password1: mypassword
}, function(data) {
if(data == 'login_wrong') {
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h21>Incorrect Login Details</h21>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $(".home_column").revertFlip()
  }, 2500);  }else{
  if(data == 'login_success') {
  $(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h21>Hello <? echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h21><br/><br/><h21>Please Wait...</h21>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   window.location = 'dashboard.php'; 
  }, 2500);

  } }
$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
});
});

</script>
```

validate_login.php, in this page I run a MySQL query to check If the username and password match. Upon a successful query I echo 'login_success' or upon a fail I echo 'login_wrong'.

validate_login.php:

```
session_start();
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_name = '$username' UNION
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 where user_name = '$username'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$hashed_pass = crypt($password, $Blowfish_Pre . $row['salt'] . $Blowfish_End);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {   // Check Username Exists

if($hashed_pass === $row['user_password_hash']) {   // Check Password is valid
$_SESSION['username']=$row['user_first_name'];      //Start User Session  
$_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];      
$_SESSION['user']=$username;
$_SESSION['username2']=$row['user_last_name'];
$_SESSION['allowance']=$row['allowance'];
$_SESSION['privelleges']=$row['privelleges'];
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET user_failed_logins = '0', user_status = 'online' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); 
$sql3 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET user_failed_logins = '0', user_status = 'online' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
$result3=mysql_query($sql2); //Start User Session

echo "login_success";
}else{
echo "login_wrong";
```

I then use my ajax code to collect these echoed values as data where I perform a check in my ajax to see if the data equals 'login_success' or login_wrong'

```
if(data == 'login_success') {
```

If the login is successful I perform an effect which causes my div to flip and display a welcome message:

```
if(data == 'login_success') {
$(".home_column").flip({
        direction:'lr',
            color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
                content:'<h21>Hello <? echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h21><br/><br/><h21>Please Wait...</h21>'
    })
```

where I have put `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` this is suppose to display the users first name where we earlier set this variable in validate_login.php. However, the ajax appears to be running before the session has time to set/start. This means the session is empty and instead of `Hello Michael`I get`Hello`.

So I am trying to echo `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` along with my `echo "login_success";` in my validate_login.php instead of in my ajax like so:

```
echo "login_success";
echo $_SESSION['username']; 
    }else{
    echo "login_wrong";
```

in theory the data (i.e. the user's name) should then be collected along with the other data 'login_success'.

However, I can I collect multiple data in ajax? because if I do this I can no longer perform an if statement to see if data = 'login_success' it just stops the whole script from working completely, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can send back data as JSON by doing so :

```
echo json_encode( array(
        "item1" => $value1,
        "item2" => $value2
    ));
```

Then in JS :

```
$.post("include/validate_login.php", {
    username1: myusername,
    password1: mypassword
}, function(json) {

    console.log(json.item1);
    console.log(json.item2);

}, 'json'); // Don't forget this
```